# Windows Phone - Binding solidcolorbrush property using dependendy property

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, dependency-properties

I have a custom control named Tile where containing a border.
I want to be able to change the Tile's border backcolor in my MainPage.xaml where I'm adding the control:

Here is the code of my tile class:

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyDpProperty = DependencyProperty.Register
        ("TileColor",
         typeof(SolidColorBrush),
         typeof(Tile),
         new PropertyMetadata(default(SolidColorBrush)));

    public SolidColorBrush TileColor
    {
        get 
        {
            return (SolidColorBrush)this.GetValue(MyDpProperty);
        }
        set 
        {       
            this.SetValue(MyDpProperty, value);
        }
    }
```

Here is the xaml from my Tile CustomControl:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="{StaticResource PhoneChromeBrush}">
    <Border Background="{Binding TileColor}"></Border>
</Grid>
```

And here is my MainPage.xaml:

```
        <local:Tile Grid.Column="5">
            <local:Tile.TileColor>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="Beige"></SolidColorBrush>
            </local:Tile.TileColor>
        </local:Tile>
```

The tile appears, but the color won't set..
Could you please point me where I'm wrong ?

Comment: Do you, by any chance, do something like `DataContext = this` in your `UserControl`? I suspect yes and if that's the case remove it, give control some name `<UserControl ... x:Name="someName">` and use it `ElementName` binding inside control instead

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not using the DataContext = this anywhere in my code. What do you mean by "use it ElementName binding inside control instead" ?

Comment: If you don't use it then overwriting `DataContext` does not look like your problem. Also your `DependencyProperty` should be called `TileColorProperty` and not `MyDpProperty`

Comment: Renaming the dependencyproperty didn't change the behaviour.

Comment: Without seeing you code I cannot tell exactly but problem seems to be in binding context. By default it will look for `TileColor` in current `DataContext` and not in `UserControl`. Like I said give `UserControl` some name `<UserControl ... x:Name="myControl">` and use `ElementName` binding `Background="{Binding ElementName=myControl, Path=TileColor}`

Answer (score -1):

You need to rename the `DependencyProperty` to `TileColorProperty` (as @dkozl says) and you also need to use `{TemplateBinding}` in the control:

**Themes\generic.xaml**

```
<ResourceDictionary
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
         xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Silverlight80App">

  <Style TargetType="local:Tile">
    <Setter Property="TileColor" Value="Aquamarine"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:Tile">
          <Rectangle Fill="{TemplateBinding TileColor}"/>
        </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
  </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

**Tile.cs**

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace Silverlight80App
{
  class Tile : ContentControl
  {
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TileColorProperty =
      DependencyProperty.Register("TileColor", typeof(Brush), typeof(Tile),
      null);

    public Brush TileColor
    {
      get { return (Brush)GetValue(TileColorProperty); }
      set { SetValue(TileColorProperty, value); }
    }

    public Tile()
    {
      DefaultStyleKey = typeof(Tile);
    }
  }
}
```

**Usage**

```
<StackPanel  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Silverlight80App">
  <local:Tile HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="10" />
  <local:Tile HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="10" TileColor="Red"/>
</StackPanel>
```